# Deploy as web app

Tags: google-apps-script

I have noticed that in Google Apps Script there is a new button saying: "Deploy as web app".

When I click on it, a panel loads asking me to whom I would like to share this project, giving them rights to run the script on my behalf.

The problem is that I can't seem to find any documentation on that and also they say that the script will be available at the url shown below, but no url is being shown, does anyone know more about this ?

Regards,

Andrei Urse
Appsbroker Consulting limited

Answer (score 2):

This issue is being tracked in the issue tracker here: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1418

In the meantime, you need to save a version of your script first, before deploying as a web app. Then, you may need to go through the deploy/update process an extra time before you see the URL displayed in the dialog. We'll update the issue tracker with progress.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to quickly find the url is to run the following function, then look at the log:

```
function getURL() {
 var service = ScriptApp.getService();
 Logger.log(service.getUrl());
}
```