# How to get url of Google sheet macro web app page?

Tags: iframe, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have a HTML page with the javascript hosted as a webapp within Google Sheets.

The web app macro page URL that I see in the address bar is different from the URL that I am seeing when I do this in my javascript.

```
  $(document).ready(function () { 
 alert(window.location.href);
 });
```

The alert is giving me URL like this:
`script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel`

While in the browser address bar, I have URL like this:

```
https://script.google.com/.../macros/fjfkdfgdkfgd
```

Any way to get the actual URL from the browser address var and save it in javascript variable which is which in my HTML page in google sheet, hosted as a web app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploy as web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102985/deploy-as-web-app)

Comment: Hi @TheMaster I get it how to get URL by a function in code.gs but in my case, my webapp is using the HTML page. Is there any way to pass a variable from code.gs to my html page so my javascript can catch it and use it? or is there any alternative method of getting the URL directly in my html page via javascript?

Comment: `google.script.run()` or htmlTemplate. Read Client-Server communication in the official documentation.

Comment: This is what I did and it is not working...In Code.gs `function getURL() {
 var service = ScriptApp.getService(); 
  var sheeturl = service.getUrl();
}` ....In my HTML web app page, I am doing this inside <script>     `$(document).ready(function () {               
     
      google.script.run.getURL();
      
 alert(sheeturl);
       }); `

Comment: Script.run is a asynchronous function. You need to use success handler to get the URL.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55171161 for Htmltemplate.  Or `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((url)=>{alert(url);}).getURL();`